# Regexp x.get(y) -> x[y]

Tags: regex, notepad++

While porting many lines of code from one language to another I must replace all array access from the form of the function call `x.get(y)` to the square brackets notation `x[y]`. There are few text editors around that can do **regular expression based replace**.

What should be typed in the "text to find" field and what should be typed in the "replace with" field in this situation? Both `x` and `y` can vary, so the original code can have lines like:

```
... state.get(1);
... text.get(i);
... result.get(line);
```

after conversion:

```
... state[1];
... text[i];
... result[line];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search for `\.get\((\w+)\)` and replace with `[$1]`.

The above pattern assumes only alphanumeric characters between the parentheses, but there are other alternatives:

- `.*` (without checking ". matched newline") should match until the end of the line.
- `[^)]*` should match characters that are not `)`. Would work for new lines.

In both cases, you *may* want to include the `;` in your pattern.

Note that this is very fragile either way - you might encounter code like `state.get(a.get(3 + sin(6)))`, and probably get incorrect results.

Answer (score 1):

For Notepad++, I would write in Find what: `([0-9,a-z,A-Z,-,_]+).get\(([0-9,a-z,A-Z,-,_]+)\)`

replace with `\1[\2]`

Input:

```
x.get(1);
text.get(i);
result.get(line);
```

Output:

```
x[1];
text[i];
result[line];
```

[image]

Comment: but both x and y are variables, please see the example

Comment: You need to escape the dot before `get`, and the commas are wrong. You've probably meant `[0-9a-zA-Z\-_]` - your pattern matches commas, and doesn't match hyphens (though, I don't know why that is necessary). Still, you could have used `[\w\-]`.

Comment: I'm not sure you know what a character class is, but your code strongly suggests you do not: you seem to think that you need to put commas between terms, but you don't. You've essentially included the comma character 5 times, which while technically not an error, is not what you intended.

Comment: @Kobi you are right about commas and dot but in notepad++ (like in question) the rules a bit different and your suggestion doesn't work. Further, the dot stays out of group so no worries. You can try to open notpad++ and try my vs your example

Comment: @Bohemian your comment is actual for regex in Java/PHP/JS ... but not in notepad++. Try to remove the commas and you will see that it doesn't work,

Comment: @MaximShoustin - I did try on the latest version of Notepad++ (6.4.5), and you are quite wrong.

Comment: lol, i have 6.4.5 too, try my answer and remove commas from `[]` it doesn't work

Comment: Not really. You should get a warning that the regex is invalid: http://i.imgur.com/CB37emb.png - that is because of the uncapped `-` in the character class. With the commas you have `,-,`. Try matching `[ab]` and `[a,b]`, and see if you catch some commas.

Comment: well, sounds like we are talking about the same case, i wrote with commas because without - doesnt work. U showed me example (image) where noteped++ drop error on no commas. So we talk about the same thing. The answer i posted works for me and sure, will work for you .

Comment: BTW, your example is better because shorter, +1